# Compile-time warning to declare array as sequence

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmpi, pgi-visual-fortran

I'm encountering a compile-time warning when passing arrays to `MPI` calls by referencing their first value. Consider the following example code, which is the leanest I could get:

```
module mymod
implicit none
contains

subroutine test_sequence(input,output,icomw,N)
use MPI
integer, intent(in), contiguous :: input(:)
integer, intent(in) :: icomw, N
integer, intent(out) :: output(:)
integer :: ier

write(*,*) 'in sub: ', is_contiguous(input), is_contiguous(output)

call MPI_REDUCE(input(1),output(1),N,MPI_INTEGER,MPI_MAX,0,icomw,ier)
   ! -- This is the line referenced in the error

end subroutine test_sequence
end module mymod

program main
use MPI
use mymod
implicit none
integer :: icomw, id, nproc, ier, N, i
integer, allocatable :: input(:), output(:)
real :: harvest

call MPI_INIT(ier)
icomw = MPI_COMM_WORLD

N = 10
allocate(input(N), output(N))
input = 1

write(*,*) 'in main: ', is_contiguous(input), is_contiguous(output)

call test_sequence(input,output,icomw,N)

call MPI_FINALIZE(ier)
end program main
```

Notice that I'm passing `MPI_REDUCE` only the first element of `input` and `output` but using a count of `N`, which is (in this case) the complete size of the array. It's worth noting that referencing array sections like this probably isn't best practice but I'm doing it anyway.

I get the following compiler warning and runtime output:

```
km-gs3% mpifort test_sequence.f90
PGF90-W-0312-Array input should be declared SEQUENCE (test_sequence.f90: 14)
PGF90-W-0312-Array output should be declared SEQUENCE (test_sequence.f90: 14)
  0 inform,   2 warnings,   0 severes, 0 fatal for test_sequence
km-gs3% mpirun -np 2 ./a.out 
 in main:   T  T
 in sub:   F  F
 in main:   T  T
 in sub:   F  F
```

I get the warning with PGI 14.3/OpenMPI 1.8.0 or PGI 15.5/OpenMPI 1.8.6. I do not get the warning with PGI 12.9/OpenMPI 1.6.2, PGI 14.3/OpenMPI 1.6.5, or Intel 14.0/OpenMPI 1.8.0.

It's my understanding that `sequence` is a keyword affecting derived data types only, and `input` and `output` here are plain integers. Also, these are 1D arrays - don't they have to be contiguous anyway?

My question is: **what's going on here? Can (and should) I declare integers as sequence?**

**Edit 1** Following the advice of francescalus, I've attempted to define the the dummy array as `contiguous`. I've added `contiguous` to the `input` argument and inquired about the contiguity (is that a word?) of `input` and `output` using `is_contiguous` in main and sub. Rather than re-post the entire code, I've edited the original code shown above. Unfortunately, I still get the same compiler warning. Furthermore, the `contiguous` attribute doesn't seem to be doing anything because `is_contiguous` reports false in the subroutine for both `input` and `output`.

Am I using the `contiguous` attribute correctly? It seems reasonable to require `input` and `output` to be `contiguous`, but not `sequence`. Perhaps I should report this to `PGI` directly, especially now that I've encountered the problem on a reasonably new version of `pgfortran`.

Comment: Can you try the `contiguous` attribute on `input`?

Comment: In the subroutine, `input` is contiguous even without the `contiguous` attribute, so the result of `is_contiguous` surprises.

Comment: @francescalus surprises indeed. Intel 14.0 gives true for `is_contiguous` everywhere for both `input` and `output`.

Comment: I've posted a related (but simpler, for now) question on PGI's forums here: https://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=4882

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now got some closure on this issue and wanted to share. This answer will hopefully provide some clarity for future readers. Thanks francescalus and Vladimir F for your help; I also received help on the [Portland Group Forums](http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=4882&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0).

There are two separate bugs in `pgfortran` at play here. The first is a bug in the `is_contiguous`  intrinsic. The second is an erroneous use of a legacy warning. Both issues have been reported and will (hopefully) be fixed in a new compiler release.

### Issue with `is_contiguous`

`is_contiguous` isn't performing as expected. The bug has been reported with tag `TPR#21939`. Consider the following example code:

```
module mymod 
implicit none 
contains 

subroutine mysub(ia1,ia2) 
integer, intent(in), contiguous :: ia1(:) 
integer, intent(in) :: ia2(:) 

write(*,*) 'in sub: ', is_contiguous(ia1), is_contiguous(ia2) 

end subroutine mysub 
end module mymod 

program main 
use mymod 
implicit none 

integer, allocatable :: ia1(:), ia2(:) 
integer :: N 

N = 10 
allocate(ia1(N), ia2(N)) 

write(*,*) 'in main: ', is_contiguous(ia1), is_contiguous(ia2) 

call mysub(ia1,ia2) 

end program main
```

which gives the following output:

```
km-gs3% pgfortran test_contiguous.f90; ./a.out 
 in main:   T  T 
 in sub:   F  F 
km-gs3% pgfortran --version 

pgfortran 15.5-0 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux -tp piledriver 
The Portland Group - PGI Compilers and Tools 
Copyright (c) 2015, NVIDIA CORPORATION.  All rights reserved.
```

Both `input` and `output` are contiguous, and I'm even assigning `ia1` the `contiguous` attribute. Yet `is_contiguous` reports them to be not contiguous in `mysub`.

### Warning to Declare as `sequence`

This is the original issue that led to this question - a compile-time warning to declare an array as `sequence`. This issue has been reported with tag `TPR#21947`. Consider the following example code:

```
module mymod 
implicit none 
contains 

subroutine test_sequence(input,output,icomw,N) 
use MPI 
integer, intent(in) :: input(:) 
integer, intent(in) :: icomw, N 
integer, intent(out) :: output(:) 
integer :: ier 

call MPI_REDUCE(input(1),output(1),N,MPI_INTEGER,MPI_MAX,0,icomw,ier) 
   ! -- This is the problem line referenced in the warning 

end subroutine test_sequence 
end module mymod 

program main 
use MPI 
use mymod 
implicit none 
integer :: icomw, id, nproc, ier, N, i 
integer, allocatable :: input(:), output(:) 
real :: harvest 

call MPI_INIT(ier) 
icomw = MPI_COMM_WORLD 

N = 10 
allocate(input(N), output(N)) 
input = 1 

call test_sequence(input,output,icomw,N) 

call MPI_FINALIZE(ier) 
end program main
```

As mentioned in the question, I'm passing the entire `input` and `output` array to `MPI_REDUCE` by referencing the first element in each array and assigning a size of `N`. This is **not** good practice, but I was doing it anyway. I get the following compile-time warning:

```
[chaud106@hyperion-login-1 Testing]$ mpif90 test_sequence.f90 
PGF90-W-0312-Array input should be declared SEQUENCE (test_sequence.f90: 12) 
PGF90-W-0312-Array output should be declared SEQUENCE (test_sequence.f90: 12) 
  0 inform,   2 warnings,   0 severes, 0 fatal for test_sequence

[chaud106@hyperion-login-1 Testing]$ mpif90 --version

pgf90 14.3-0 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux -tp piledriver 
The Portland Group - PGI Compilers and Tools
Copyright (c) 2014, NVIDIA CORPORATION.  All rights reserved.
[chaud106@hyperion-login-1 Testing]$ mpirun --version
mpirun (Open MPI) 1.8

Report bugs to http://www.open-mpi.org/community/help/
```

which is incorrect because arrays (like `input`) may not be defined as `sequence`.

Comment: @francescalus good points. I've edited my answer to include `ia2` to be contiguous. I'm unfamiliar with the term *element sequence* but I would be unhappy to see the warning turned into an error as mkcolg suggests on the Portland forum. Perhaps you'd like to post there yourself?

Comment: [Tidied up the wrong comment first, so context lacking.]  Whether there is an error depends on the dummy argument.  From memory, pre-MPI 3 the arguments of `MPI_Reduce` are assumed-size, so this element sequence (see F2008 12.5.2.11) is permitted.  However, I could be wrong (it's been a while since I looked at this) and with the interface actually assumed-shape.  (And this is potentially a difference between the module and `mpif.h`, and in particular the `mpi_f08` module and that with assumed type/rank etc.)

Comment: I'm using 1.8.0 - edited the question to include version and such.

Comment: I'm in danger of not making sense (and I missed the version details in the question), but I'll try.  There are times when having the array element corresponding to a dummy array is fine, and some times when not.  An error should be given only in this latter case.  With MPI, until all but the most recent standards of Fortran, MPI one didn't really want to pay attention to what the rules say...

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to the same setup to be able to replicate, but there are some things still to say.

The `sequence` attribute can indeed apply only to derived types.  That means you can't (and shouldn't) declare `input` and `output` with `sequence`.

Now, after we note that what you see is a warning (which has prompted you to think about the problem - which you can do more than the compiler can), what are the other concerns?

There are several implications that come from being a sequence type.  Continguity is an important one, and is addressed in your penultimate question.

A 1D dummy argument, such as `input`, needn't be contiguous.  Consider

```
  real a(11), b(5)
  call sub(a(1::5))    ! Look at the stride
  call sub(b(5:1:-1))  ! Look at the order

contains

   subroutine sub(input)
     real, intent(in) :: input(:)
   end subroutine

end program
```

In general, in Fortran we don't have to care about the contiguity or otherwise of dummy arguments.  There is, though, the `is_contiguous` intrinsic function which inquires of the contiguity of an array.

When interfacing with other things there may be reason to worry.  There are some things you can do here:

- thorough testing (how does the compiler/MPI environment really handle things?)
- add the `contiguous` attribute to the dummy arguments
- pass the arrays themselves to `MPI_Reduce`, not the first elements

Comment: Looks like PGF actually means `contiguous` when they write `sequence`. It is  the sequence association that is happening after all.

Comment: That makes sense.  If Ross can confirm that the message goes away with `contiguous` I'll add to the answer.

Comment: @francescalus Thanks for the answer. I've attempted to use `contiguous` with no success. I've updated my answer just now. I also tried a very recent version of PGF.

Comment: My *question* just now, sorry.